# Upgrading seekers armguard

Tags: league-of-legends

[Seeker's Armguard](http://leaguepedia.com/wiki/Seeker's_Armguard) has a unique mechanic where it gives .5 armor and ap for every minion kill (max of 15 armor/ap).

What happens to these bonus stats when upgrading the item to a [Zhonya's Hourglass](http://leaguepedia.com/wiki/Zhonya%27s_Hourglass)?  Do the bonus stats persist?  Is it more beneficial to max out Seeker's Armguard before upgrading it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no bonus for stacking Seeker's Armguards before upgrading it to Zhonya's Hourglass. The stats of Zhonya's Hourglass are static regardless if you buy it outright or have the components for it before upgrading.

Source: http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=3067192